# Compatibility a jquery code in various browsers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, compatibility

I have a simply code:

```
<?php
  if( isset($_POST['cnt']) ) {
    $_SESSION['counter'] += 1;
  }
  echo $_SESSION['counter'];
  echo '<button id="b1">Count</button>';
?>

<script>
    $("#b1").click(function(){
      $.post("index.php", { cnt: 1 });
      location.reload();
    });
</script>
```

The script without problems counts clicks on Chrome or Edge, but it completely doesn't work on FF and IE. Where could be the problem ?

Comment: What doesn't work?  What is your question?

Comment: Put `location.reload();` in your success callback..

Comment: @Amstell I do not know why the counter does not increase value after refreshing page on FF?

Comment: @RayonDabre Could you explain? I started to learn jQuery yesterday.

Comment: Your page is getting refreshed before ajax call is being completed...

Comment: *"but it completely doesn't work on FF and IE."* - what might those versions be?

Comment: @RayonDabre Ok. How should I write it correctly?

Comment: @Fred-ii- FF 43 and IE11

Comment: use error reporting and check your developer console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your js code to:

PHP:

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['cnt']) ) {
  $_['counter'] += 1;
} else {
  $_['counter'] = 0;
}
echo '<p id="val">' + $_['counter'] + '</p>';
echo '<button id="b1">Count</button>';
```

JS:

```
$("#b1").click(function(){
  $.post("index.php", { cnt: 1 }, function(data) {
    location.reload();
  });
});
```

Comment: @PjRain Thanks for accepting my answer. Could you now upvote if it is possible? Thanks

Comment: I wanted. but I have a too low reputation